# Textillate works locally but not on live site

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the plugin Textillate to animate some text on my site.

I have developed the site locally to my liking and today I decided I wanted to transfer it to a live site. After doing so , textillate breaks. I've double checked my localhost and my live server are running the same version of php.

Why is this happening? What could cause an error on the live site, but not locally? It doesn't make much sense to me. All files are included, everything is word for word the same.

Comment: the only error I get in the console on the live site is

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'textillate' `

but on the local site, not a single error is generated.

Comment: Is the path to textillate.js correct?  It might be helpful to post a link for people to see.   You should also remove the php tag and put javascript / css3 as tags as it doesn't have anything to do with php

Comment: you probably need to add the script to the header `<script type='text/javascript' src='yourpath/jquery.textillate.js'></script>`

Comment: So you down rep me because I tagged it wrong? How kind of you.

Anyway, textillate is included in the header along with all the dependencies (lettering, animate.css and then textillate.) I can see them all under scripts in the inspector, so I know they are all included and loaded properly.

For whatever reason, I can't seem to figure out - on my live site two version of jQuery are loading, while on the local site only one is. That is most likely the culprit , but I can't find or deque or deregister the jquery.

Comment: Adding '<?php wp_head(); ?>' to the top of my file gets everything running, but creates separate errors. I must be hooking in to wp_head somewhere with something that is helping me.

Comment: clearly something is just hugely messed up. I've never had an issue of working locally, transferring it live and everything's fked up. never.